# Responsive menu not showing after clicking on bar icon

Tags: html, css, menu, responsive

I'm trying to do my first website with the tutorial on YouTube, but I'm stuck on this.

On mobile devices I want my menu to look like this (screen with red background) but when I click on the icon, nothing happens.

[image]

[image]

Does somebody have any idea on how to make it work? Thanks in advance for your help.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Lora', serif;
}

.header {
  /*overflow: hidden; */
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  padding: 2% 6%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

nav img {
  width: 150px;
}

.nav-links {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: right;
}

.nav-links ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: relative;
}

.nav-links ul li a {
  color: #515675;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.nav-links ul li::after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #E3AAAF;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.nav-links ul li:hover::after {
  background: #515675;
}

.text-box {
  width: 90%;
  color: #515675;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.text-box h1 {
  font-size: 62px;
}

.text-box p {
  margin: 10px 0 42px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #515675;
}

.hero-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #515675;
  border: 1px solid #515675;
  padding: 12px 34px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background: transparent;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hero-btn:hover {
  border: 1px solid #E3AAAF;
  background: #E3AAAF;
  transition: 1s;
}

nav .fa-solid {
  display: none;
}

@media(max-width: 700px) {
  * {
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  .text-box h1 {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .nav-links ul li {
    display: block;
  }
  .nav-links {
    position: absolute;
    background: #515675;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 200px;
    top: 0;
    right: -200px;
    text-align: left;
    z-index: 2;
  }
  nav .fa-solid {
    display: block;
    color: #515675;
    margin: 10px;
    font-size: 22px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .nav-links ul {
    padding: 30px;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title> Beauty by Name </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <!--<link href="<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lora:ital,wght@0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/961cf6a213.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.2/css/all.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <section class="header">
    <nav>
      <a href="index.html"><img class="logo" style="width: 200px;" src="images/logo.jpg" alt=""></a>
      <div class="nav-links">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark"></i>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Offer</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i>
    </nav>

    <div class="text-box">
      <h1>Beauty By YOUR Name</h1>
      <p>We are dedicated to enhancing your natural charm, offering a range of tailored treatments and pampering experiences. <br> Step into our serene oasis and let us bring out your inner glow.</p>
      <a href="" class="hero-btn">Contact us</a>
    </div>

  </section>

</body>
```

Comment: Hi Martyna, welcome to SO! As you are doing a tutorial I am not going to show you how to do this, but ask a question instead: where is the code that 'catches the click' and then 'opens the menu'? There are enough qestions/answers on SO explaining the *hamburger menu*....

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. What I have added in the code:

html:

```
<script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            const menuIcon = document.querySelector('.fa-bars');
            const closeIcon = document.querySelector('.fa-xmark');
            const navLinks = document.querySelector('.nav-links');
    
            menuIcon.addEventListener('click', function() {
                navLinks.classList.toggle('show');
            });
    
            closeIcon.addEventListener('click', function() {
                navLinks.classList.remove('show');
            });
        });
    </script>
```

css:

```
.show {
right: 0;}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).